# jquery datepicker is not working in partial view

Tags: jquery

Datepicker jquery is not working in view which is returned as partial view.

in main view :

```
      <link href="~/css/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,

            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', beforeShow: function () {
                $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 12)

            },

        });



  </script>
```

in second view:

```
<td >
 <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="datepicker" />
  </td>
```

in controller:

```
return PartialView(secondView);
```

given jquery in main view only

edited: datepicker call at ajax success

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/a/b/',
            data: { datepicker: $('#datepicker').val(), id: id },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var htmldata = $.parseHTML(data);
                if (id == 1) {
                    $('#a').html(data);
                    $(".datepicker").datepicker();

                }
                else { $('#a').html(data); $(".datepicker").datepicker(); }


            },

        });

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your code as shown below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     (function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,

            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', beforeShow: function () {
                $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 12)
            },
        });
          })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

put thses line just after the rendering of partial view instead of putting them in the partial view:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,

            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', beforeShow: function () {
                $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 12)

            },

        });



  </script>
```

If loading via ajax call write this script in success function after appending the partial view to the page, if using Razor helper right just after that statement.

Comment: I have done as you said but it is not working..in ajax call success

Comment: can you please check it once

Comment: if you update the post with what you changed i can check

Comment: @Priya any joy with your datepicker? I'm having the same problem